# error overloaded method value regexp_replace with alternatives

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark-sql, databricks, regexp-replace

I'm trying to replace the "/" character with space(" ") from data in a column called UserAgent in a dataframe df_test

Data in the column looks like this:

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko

I have tried using

```
val df_test =spark.sql(s"select UserAgent from df_header_pivot")
 df_test.withColumn("UserAgent", regexp_replace("UserAgent", "[/]", ""))
```

but I'm getting error message:

> notebook:4: error: overloaded method value regexp_replace with alternatives:
>     (e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,pattern: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,replacement: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.Column 
>     (e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,pattern: String,replacement: String)org.apache.spark.sql.Column
>    cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName, org.apache.spark.sql.Column)
>   df_test.withColumn("UserAgent", regexp_replace($"UserAgent" , lit("/")))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `$` symbol before the column name in `regexp_replace` function.

`import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df_test =spark.sql(s"select UserAgent from df_header_pivot")
df_test.withColumn("UserAgent", regexp_replace($"UserAgent", "[/]", " "))`

Comment: Nice answer Vijay!

Answer (score 1):

As you are using SparkSQL, you could simply call the `replace` function in the SQL itself, eg something like this:

```
val df_test =spark.sql(s"select replace(UserAgent, '/', '') AS UserAgent from tmp")

df_test.show
```

Alternately use the `translate` function to replace characters where no regex is required, eg

```
df_test
  .withColumn("UserAgent", translate($"UserAgent", "/", ""))
  .show
```

No regex required.

Comment: Hey wBob, it is possible in scala/python also ?

Comment: Hey @VijayKumarSharma, check my answer with updated use of `translate` function. HTH